# onPreviewFrame and Exception locking surface

Tags: android, android-camera, android-canvas

I'm trying to lockCanvas() because I want to modify camera picture before preview. I do it in 
onPreviewFrame.

Code is here:

```
public class MyPreview implements Camera.PreviewCallback {

        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.d("Camera", "Got a camera frame");

            Canvas c = null;

            try {
                    c = mCamSH.lockCanvas(null);

                    Log.d("SOMETHING", "Got Bitmap");
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    mCamSH.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }

    } //public class MyPreview implements Camera.PreviewCallback
```

Unfortunately I always got this error in a loop, problem is with  c = mCamSH.lockCanvas(null);  :

```
E/SurfaceHolder﹕ Exception locking surface
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
            at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:76)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$4.internalLockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:831)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$4.lockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:811)
            at cz.mrp.camera.CamActivity$MyPreview.onPreviewFrame(CamActivity.java:100)
            at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:773)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Whole code is here: http://pastebin.com/WJs1kyfq

Using Android 4.0.4 on GT-S7562 device.

I already tried to search here on StackOverflow and used google as well, but didn't find anything what could help me. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm facing same issue, but it occurs in S8 only/ how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 8):

You can't do that.

A Surface isn't a buffer, it's a queue of buffers in a producer-consumer arrangement.  There can only be one producer at a time, and that's the Camera, so you can't lock the Surface for software rendering.  There's no way to read data back out of a Surface unless your app is also the consumer, so there's no way to modify the frame with your current arrangement.

The most efficient way to go about this depends on what it is you're trying to do.  If you just want to put an overlay on the preview, you can do that with a custom View with a transparent background.  If you want to modify the image before saving it as a still image, then also modify the single still frame before you save it to disk.  If you want to modify it for video recording, you can use a SurfaceTexture as the preview target (which gives you both producer and consumer ends in the app), and then use GLES to modify the image.  The "show + capture camera" activity in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) demonstrates the latter.

See also the [Android System-Level Graphics Architecture](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html) doc.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution.

You have to remove this code because the canvas is already locked by camera.

```
mCam.setPreviewDisplay(mCamSH);
```

In order to show camera preview, you have to draw it manually by using the variable(byte[] data) on the canvas.

Comment: In my case I can't remove that line, but your suggestion helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use

```
c = mCamSH.lockCanvas(null);
```

?

Try this:

```
c = mCamSH.lockCanvas();
```

**@Edit**
You are trying to call lockCanvas on mCamSH holder.
This holder however, is used by camera so the canvas is already locked by it.

To keep it short: i don't think you can call lockCanvas inside of onPreviewFrame

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately the problem is still the same :(. Remove the parameter from lockCanvas didn't help.